# How to combine a min-width with a max-width that equals to 100% if needed in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I'm looking for CSS rules that allow setting fixed element width (let's say `width: 500px`), but combines it with `max-width: 100%` if a container is narrower than the element.

I'm thinking about something similar to:

```
.elem {
 width: 600px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

This snippet works perfect - if a `.elem`'s container is narrower than the `.elem` itself, the `.elem` has container's width - smaller than `600px`.

How to achieve the same effect with `min-width`? The following snippet doesn't work:

```
.elem {
 min-width: 600px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

Maybe any ideas using CSS Grid or even JavaScript?

Comment: I think you want `width: 100%; max-width: 600px`

Comment: Why do you wan't to use `min-width`?

Comment: min-width is stronger than max-width, that's why your element will never be less than 600px

Comment: I want to use `min-width`, because buttons in my application have a minimum of `320px`. But if the screen is narrower (the smallest mobile screens) I want to limit the width to the screen width minus paddings, or other containers. But if a button has long text (longer than 320px), the button has to be wider. To sum up - I need something similiar to combination of `min-width: 320px` and `max-width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX) is your answer in this case.
The clamp() CSS function clamps a value between an upper and lower bound. clamp() enables selecting a middle value within a range of values between a defined minimum and maximum. It takes three parameters: a minimum value, a preferred value, and a maximum allowed value. The clamp() function can be used anywhere a length, frequency, angle, time, percentage, number, or integer is allowed.

clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX) is resolved as max()(MIN, min()(VAL, MAX))

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for someting alike :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  /* demo purpose */
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
  /* flex optionnal */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

button {
  min-width: clamp(320px, 600px, 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class>
  <button>hello</button>
  <button> hello hello hello</button>
  <button> hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</button>

</div>
```

320px (can be 0 to X )  is the min-width you agree width, 600px the max-width you allow and 100% the limit not to pass.

here is a pen to test and play with : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGqyJmL

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` cannot overwrite `width` in your written code, I think same as **@dantheman**. you might looking for `width: 100%; max-width: 600px min-width: 320px`.
It will take the whole container but not higher than 600px and not smaller than 320px.

Comment: The most difficult case is when I have a container equals to `320px` with unknown paddings (let's say 16px). Then my element should have `288px` of width. But container's paddings and width are different depending on context and in general unknown.

Comment: I don't quite understand, if you want it smaller than 320px you can remove min-width so it can get smaller as your container gets. can you explain more?